# How to change size of JCheckBox Swing?

Tags: java, user-interface

I been working on some touchscreen app, so I need to make standard JCheckboxes more bigger. So, I tried with setMaximumSize and setPrefferedSize, but it didn't make changes at all. Any suggestion? Thanks in an advance.

Comment: Could you add the code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make JCheckbox bigger..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770022/make-jcheckbox-bigger)

Comment: @Ayush I don't know how to implement it. Can you give more info about implementing it?

Comment: The two answers in the link both have implementations provided, if you face a specific problem with an implementation of your own, consider opening a new question.